# How do I iterate over each message in a Flink DataStream?

Tags: apache-flink, flink-streaming

I have a message stream from Kafka like the following

```
DataStream<String> messageStream = env
  .addSource(new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>(topic, new MsgPackDeserializer(), props));
```

How can I iterate over each message in the stream and do something with it? I see an `iterate()` method on `DataStream` but it does not return an `Iterator<String>`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think you are looking for a `MapFunction`.

```
DataStream<String> messageStream = env.addSource(
    new FlinkKafkaConsumer09<>(topic, new MsgPackDeserializer(), props));

DataStream<Y> mappedMessages = messageStream
  .map(new MapFunction<String, Y>() {
    public Y map(String message) {
      // do something with each message and return Y
    }
  });
```

If you don't want to emit exactly one record for each incoming message, have a look at the `FlatMapFunction`.